# Google Chrome - Storing Youtube Data Indefinately

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, youtube

I use Google chrome as my browser, and when I'm outside of my home, I often tether my laptop to my phone for internet.

I sometimes listen to music or watch videos on youtube in the aforementioned circumstance, often repeating the same videos.

Is it possible to configure the browser to store the data from the videos /forever/ (or at least longer) because I've even left my computer on for a couple days, and as soon as I go offline the video will bug at some point.

It seems senseless to be continually reloading streamed videos and in so doing, eat up all of my limited data.

If the browser can temporarily store the video (which it must do) is there some way to extend the lifetime of that data?